# How keep in the secret the RSA - private key in browser - implement Proof of Possession with an Asymmetric Key

Tags: browser, rsa, jwt

I want to implement the `Proof of Possession` with an Asymmetric Key [specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800).

I would like to store the RSA in secure place in the browser - I will be able to sign the part of the request with private key and with public key as part of JWT verify the request.

I don't know how import RSA into my browser - where can I store RSA private key secure in browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the WebCrypto API and IndexedDB. There are some WebCrypto examples here - https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples.

This will allow you to import the key in a way that it cannot be extracted - only used to sign and verify signatures. This will however be wiped when browser data is cleared with the "clear application data" (/similar - depends on browser) flag is ticked.

For example to import a key and store it in an IndexedDB (this code hasn't been tested / _openDb would have to be implemented) -

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
    {   //this is an example jwk key, other key types are Uint8Array objects
        kty: "RSA",
        e: "AQAB",
        n: "vGO3eU16ag9zRkJ4AK8ZUZrjbtp5xWK0LyFMNT8933evJoHeczexMUzSiXaLrEFSyQZortk81zJH3y41MBO_UFDO_X0crAquNrkjZDrf9Scc5-MdxlWU2Jl7Gc4Z18AC9aNibWVmXhgvHYkEoFdLCFG-2Sq-qIyW4KFkjan05IE",
        alg: "PS256",
        ext: true,
    },
    {   //these are the algorithm options
        name: "RSA-PSS",
        hash: {name: "SHA-256"}, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
    },
    false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
    ["verify"] //"verify" for public key import, "sign" for private key imports
).then(function(key){
    ((_db_handle === null) ?
        _openDb() :
        Promise.resolve()
    ).then(function() {
        let tx = _db_handle.transaction("KeyStore", "readwrite");
        let store = tx.objectStore("KeyStore");

        let putKey = store.put({id: "Key 1", key: key});

        putKey.onsuccess = function() {
            resolve();
        };

        putKey.onerror = function() {
            reject(putKey.error);
        };
    });
})
```

Then to read it back out -

```
let tx = _db_handle.transaction("KeyStore", "readwrite");
let store = tx.objectStore("KeyStore");

let getKey = store.get("Key 1");

getKey.onsuccess = function() {
    resolve(getKey.result ? getKey.result.key : null);
};

getKey.onerror = function() {
    reject(getKey.error);
};
```

Comment: What about Web Crypto support in older browsers?

Comment: For a security specific application i would argue against supporting out of date browsers. It works in the latest Chrome, IE, Opera & Firefox afaik. It would be worth checking Safari. Its been in chrome since 2014 - which by browser standards is ancient.

Comment: For WebCrypto in older browsers, you can use https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner. This implements algorithms in JS so it is possible for your application to work downlevel HOWEVER the security properties of JS crypto are not the same if possible encorage users to upgrade to a more modern browser instead.

Comment: The latest Safari does support WebCrypto. You can test what is supported by various WebCrypto implementations with this https://peculiarventures.github.io/pv-webcrypto-tests/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an extension for holding keys. Consider that if you need to store private keys in a browser, you should only allow to store encrypted  keys per default and in addition if you want/need to store more keys don't allow the same password on different key files.

Also consider using a master key and/or OTPs to decrypt the store.

Looking for an extension where these things are available could save some work

Comment: What do you mean with extension? What do you think about storing the key into cookie? Can you please provide some URL to your concept which you are mentioned?

Comment: i mean a browser extension and storing a private KeyFile in a Cookie ... does not sound as it is a good practice... what would u prefere as a user a hidden key handling or a visible one ? cookies can be deleted, captured and so on... i don`t think that'sa good idea .... OTP is a OneTimePassword https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238, you may know it from goolge authentifiactor ore 2 way loginauthentification

Comment: maybe you can store your keys in the browsers password vaults, could also be a good solution and it is implemented already

Comment: OK and can you send spec around MasterKey concept? It's might be good point as well.